# jQuery Mobile + PhoneGap : Issues with iOS build - Splash screen and page transitions

Tags: jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am working on a small app using jQuery Mobile and Phonegap so I can make it available on Android and iOS devices.

The Android build was going pretty smooth but today when I did the first iOS build, there were some "weird" graphical issues.

To start with, the splash screen showed at launch (as expected) but then seemed to "shrink" and show a lot of white behind it before it disappeared (as the app had loaded).

Secondly, when clicking on a link to an internal "page" (a div defined with a data-role within the index.html file - there are about 6, small "pages" like this) you could momentarily see the pages content flicker before the page transition, and finally showing the content. Clearly it should not behave like this.

The Android build has zero issues with the splash screen or navigating to the internal pages.

To clarify, I am using jQuery 1.7.1, jQuery Mobile 1.1.0, phonegap.js (so it uses the latest version) and I am testing on a HTC Desire running CyanogenMod 7.1 and an iPhone 4 (unsure of iOS version, its my colleagues)

The only "mobileinit" setting I have is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
            $.mobile.loadingMessage = 'Loading...' ;
        });
</script>
```

Any ideas folks?